# Where can I find the official data of all cities in the United States?

Tags: united-states

I would like to see a list of all U.S. cities and have them categorized by states.

Is there any authority web link I can follow?

I searched on Google but the list is limited. I want to have a full one.

Answer (score 4):

Try the US census data.  For example:  https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2017/demo/popest/total-cities-and-towns.html#tables

Each state will have its own GIS data of cities (and other political entities), but the US Census has every municipality of every kind, for every state. Keep in mind that a "city", in the US, is a municipality: a political entity with a government and defined boundaries. There are other kinds of municipalities that you might also think of as "cities"; or you might be thinking of metro areas around a city proper (which the US Census also tabulates).

Comment: I concur with US Census. Each state will have its own GIS data of cities (and other political entities), but the US Census has every municipality of every kind, for every state.

Keep in mind that a "city", in the US, is a municipality: a political entity with a government and defined boundaries. There are other kinds of municipalities that you might also think of as "cities"; or you might be thinking of metro areas around a city proper (which the US Census also tabulates).

Comment: I have downloaded the data. There are 758 cities. Can I understand the number as the total city count? That every one in the US can be from a place in that 758 cities?

Comment: @AGamePlayer I'm sure the Census bureau has a definition of what a City is based on population, size, etc. you might want to find out what is included in that 758 cities

Comment: @Nathan added your comments to the answer as i think they are valuable (and the message was the answer was too short...(

Comment: @AGamePlayer, no. A city is just one type of "place" that the census bureau tabulates. Census "places" include all incorporated municipalities (including cities and various other types), and a number of unincorporated "census designated places".

For complete geographic coverage that encompasses the total population, use the data for "county subdivisions". Some of the city "places" are also tabulated as county subdivision (where they are coextensive), but not all; and there are many other types that cover the remaining geographic area.

More: https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/terms.html